# Why scaling the vector and matrix give totally different result in Scipy optimization

Tags: python, math, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I have the following optimization scheme:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

#Define problem
A = np.array([[60., 90., 120.], 
              [30., 120., 90.]])

b = np.array([6700.5, 699.,])

def f(x):
    return np.linalg.norm(A.dot(x) - b)

cons ={'type': 'eq',
       'fun': lambda x: sum(x) - 1}

x0 = [1, 0, 0]  # initial guess
minimize(f, x0, method='SLSQP', bounds=((0, np.inf),)*3, constraints=cons)
```

Which gives the following output:

```
  status: 0
 success: True
    njev: 2
    nfev: 10
     fun: 6608.620222860367
       x: array([ 0.,  0.,  1.])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     jac: array([ -62.50927734, -100.675354  , -127.78314209,    0.        ])
     nit: 2
```

This works fine as expected. But next what I'm trying to do is to *normalize* or scale the vector `b` and matrix `A` by doing this and put it right before `def f(x)`.

```
A = A/np.linalg.norm(A,axis=0)
b = b/np.linalg.norm(b)
```

Now the result is totally different

```
  x: array([ 1.,  0.,  0.])
```

My question are

- Why the two solutions are different?
- What's the best way to scale `A` and `b` so that the result become consistent?

Comment: You can't scale `A` and `b` with different factors.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: Thanks. How do you suggest the better way to do it?

Comment: Depends on why you want to do this. You could choose the maximum of both factors as your scaling factor.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: Both `A` and `b` are gene expression data. And 'b' are composed by element of `A` as much as `x` percent, e.g. `a1x1+a2x2 +a3x3 = b`.

Comment: I would expect the answers to be different.  The scaling of the matrix equation must be applied consistently.  It should also allow you to transform between scaled and unscaled answers as well.  It's a new vector space.

Comment: @duffymo: How would you suggest the best way to do it?

Comment: The obvious answer: use a consistent scaling matrix for the the left and right hand sides of your equation.  Anything else is invalid linear algebra.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Is there a reason, why you are not using the squared error (i.e. ``np.linalg.norm(A.dot(x) - b)**2``)? You could use ``np.linalg.lstsq()`` then.